cqrs how to handle cascading updates in projection
I have an aggregate product on write side in relation db
Product:
Id
Name
Cost
CategoryID

EventStore:
eventId      version       data                                          eventType                                                                        
 uuid1        1     [id: 1, name: orange, cost: 100, category_id: 4]   CreateProductEvent
 uuid1        2         [name: apple]                                  ChangeNameEvent                                                                          
 uuid2        2         [cost: 200]                                    ChangeCostEvent                                                             
 uuid3        3         [name: tomato]                                 ChangeNameEvent                                          

On the reading side I accept events and update the projection in elastic. Resulting projection:
{
"id": 1,
"name": tomato,
"cost": 200,
"category_id": 4
}

I have a category table in the db
category_id   name
   4         products

And now on the reading side I want to denormalize category_id:
{
"id": 1,
"name": tomato,
"cost": 200,
"category": {
  id: 4,
  name: "products"
  }
}

How to handle the situation when someone wants to change category name? How to update all projections that includes this category?

I create CategoryNameChangedEvent on write side and on read size search all projections and updates them. But while I'm doing this, there may be parallel events that create a projection with old category name.
I search all products on write side and create event for each of them. There could be millions of such events, errors may occur and so on.
How to handle this problem?

